# Facebook - You don't have permission to access "http://www.yourapp/?" on this server

Tags: facebook, permissions, access-denied, permission-denied

Users are getting the following message when trying to use my Facebook app:

> Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://www.myapp/?"  on this server.
>
> Reference #18.8f265dcc.1338297690.20407019

It works when going directly to the app (http://www.myapp/), but not through Facebook.

I have a secured version (https) that works both directly and through Facebook.

This was working fine last week.  I haven't made an update since 5/10, and now it's just broken.  Did Facebook change something???

Help!

Comment: That error message is shown when exactly? As a part of using `FB.ui`?

Answer (score 0):

"http://www.myapp/?" si not a secure connection. Check the settings in your facebook app. You have to use secure connection if your not in developer mode.

Comment: Correct.  I have my app set up so users can use a secured OR an unsecured site.  (I have an http version AND and https version.)  The unsecured version worked just fine until this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to fix the problem, but I did find a workaround.  I'm sharing it, in case others have the same problem.

Basically, I got rid of the unsecured version altogether.  I went into my developer panel and changed the link in my "Canvas URL" to point to my secured version, instead of the unsecured one.  As a bonus, I now only have once set of production code to maintain.